# Computing distances on inhomogeneous vectors: python lists vs numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distance

In my project (about clustering algorithms, specifically k-medoids) is crucial to be able to compute pairwise distances efficiently. I have a dataset of ~60,000 objects. The problem is, distances must be computed between inhomogeneous vectors, i.e. vectors which may differ in length (in that case, missing items are treated as if they were 0).

Here is a minimal working example:

```py
# %%
MAX_LEN = 11
N = 100

import random

def manhattan_distance(vec1, vec2):
    n1, n2 = len(vec1), len(vec2)
    n = min(n1, n2)
    dist = 0
    for i in range(n):
        dist += abs(vec1[i] - vec2[i])
    if n1 > n2:
        for i in range(n, n1):
            dist += abs(vec1[i])
    else:
        for i in range(n, n2):
            dist += abs(vec2[i])
    return dist

def compute_distances():
    n = len(data)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            manhattan_distance(data[i], data[j])

data = []
for i in range(N):
    data.append([])
    for k in range(random.randint(5, MAX_LEN)):
        data[i].append(random.randint(0, 10))

%timeit compute_distances()

import numpy as np

def manhattan_distance_np(vec1, vec2):
    return np.absolute(vec1 - vec2).sum()

def compute_distances_np():
    n = len(data)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            manhattan_distance_np(data_np[i], data_np[j])

data_np = [np.append(np.asarray(d), np.zeros(MAX_LEN - len(d))) for d in data]

%timeit compute_distances_np()
```

I was testing my Python lists implementation versus a `numpy` implementation.
Here are the results (computation times):

1. Python lists: `79.6 ms ± 3.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`
2. `numpy` arrays: `226 ms ± 7.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Why is there such a huge difference? I supposed `numpy` arrays were really fast.
Is there a way to improve my code? Am I misunderstanding the inner workings of `numpy`?

Edit: I may need, in the future, to be able to use a custom distance function for pairwise distances computations. The method should work also for data sets of length 60'000 without running out of memory.

Comment: You aren't really using the strengths of `numpy`. What are the sizes of your vectors?

Comment: Also, this line: `data_np = np.zeros(N)` is totally useless. It's hard to follow what you are doing.

Comment: How can I use the strengths of `numpy`? Is there any good guide about it?

Anyway, in the example above the sizes of the vectors vary between 5 and 11. To be able to use `numpy` for Manhattan distance computation, I made them all of length 11 (adding zeros when necessary).

Comment: That line was indeed useless, I removed it now.
I am just making an example data set with vectors of integer with a length varying from 5 to 11. For the `numpy` version I just added zeros where necessary, so that any vector would be of length 11 exactly. Anyway, `numpy` performs way worse than the plain list implementation.

Comment: `numpy`'s strengths lie on vectorized computations over entire arrays, you essentially make a lot of little arrays, then loop over a `list` of arrays, then do the vectorized operations on these little arrays. I wouldn't expect that to be faster than a naive implementation, especially with a size of about 11. You should put all your data in a giant array and then try to use [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py#L1141) This should be fastest if your N is very large, because it can be parallelized.

Comment: But note, parallelization in CPython has a huge overhead, because you need to start separate processes. You'll see real gains if that overhead is small with respect to the size of your data, but if it is on the order of N=100 and MAX_LEN=11, just go with lists.

Comment: The problem is, I might need (in the future) to define a custom distance function. Anyway, I will look into the giant array for the data.

Comment: Also, that `scikit-learn` function is basically a wrapper around this [scipy-function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist). If you can put your arrays into a single multi-dimensional array, use the scipy implementation. This will certainly be faster for big arrays as well, because the actual distance metric and looping is done in compiled C code, rather than on the Python interpreter level.

Comment: The real data set will have N=60'000 approximately. I already had problems of memory, because I can't precompute all pairwise distances and store that giant dissimilarity matrix in memory.

Comment: Well, if you *really* need speed with a custom function, you should consider writing a C-extension with Cython. Alternatively, you can look into JIT compilation with `numba`, that lets your write Python code on `numpy` arrays, but it if you are working with fixed-size numpy arrays, it will compile your loops!

Comment: Thank you! I will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found probably the most straightforward way to solve this problem without changing too much the code and rely solely on computations and not on memory (since that could be unfeasible for very large datasets).

Based on juanpa.arrivillaga suggestion, I tried `numba`, that is a library that speeds up array-oriented and math-heavy Python code and is targeted mainly at `numpy`. You can read a good guide on optimizing Python code here: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2015/02/24/optimizing-python-with-numpy-and-numba/.

```py
MAX_LEN = 11
N = 100

# Pure Python lists implementation.
import random

def manhattan_distance(vec1, vec2):
    n1, n2 = len(vec1), len(vec2)
    n = min(n1, n2)
    dist = 0
    for i in range(n):
        dist += abs(vec1[i] - vec2[i])
    if n1 > n2:
        for i in range(n, n1):
            dist += abs(vec1[i])
    else:
        for i in range(n, n2):
            dist += abs(vec2[i])
    return dist

def compute_distances():
    n = len(data)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            manhattan_distance(data[i], data[j])

data = []
for i in range(N):
    data.append([])
    for k in range(random.randint(5, MAX_LEN)):
        data[i].append(random.randint(0, 10))

%timeit compute_distances()

# numpy+numba implementation.
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit
def manhattan_distance_np(vec1, vec2):
    return np.absolute(vec1 - vec2).sum()

@jit
def compute_distances_np():
    n = len(data)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            manhattan_distance_np(data_np[i], data_np[j])

data_np = np.array([np.append(np.asarray(d), np.zeros(MAX_LEN - len(d))) for d in data])

%timeit compute_distances_np()
```

Timing output:

```py
%timeit compute_distances()
78.4 ms ± 3.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit compute_distances_np()
4.1 ms ± 14.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As you can see, the `numpy` with `numba` optimizations is about 19 times faster (with no other code optimization involved).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just make your arrays dense and set the unused last elements to 0s.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist, squareform


def batch_pdist(x, metric, batchsize=1000):
    dists = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    for i in range(0, len(x), batchsize):
        for j in range(0, len(x), batchsize):
            dist_batch = cdist(x[i:i+batchsize], x[j:j+batchsize], metric=metric)
            dists[i:i+batchsize, j:j+batchsize] = dist_batch

    return dists


MIN_LEN = 5
MAX_LEN = 11
N = 10000
M = 10

data = []
data = np.zeros((N,MAX_LEN))
for i in range(N):
    num_nonzero = np.random.randint(MIN_LEN, MAX_LEN)
    data[i, :num_nonzero] = np.random.randint(0, M, num_nonzero)

dists = squareform(pdist(data, metric='cityblock'))
dists2 = batch_pdist(data, metric='cityblock', batchsize=500)
print((dists == dists2).all())
```

Timing Output:

```
%timeit squareform(pdist(data, metric='cityblock'))
43.8 µs ± 134 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Edit:

For a custom distance function see the very bottom of this [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist).

Comment: Thank you!
What if I need to specify a custom distance function?

Comment: And what if `N = 60000`? I run out of memory.

Comment: See the edit for the custom distance function. I will add another edit for the question about large N

Comment: Thank you! I only just realized that my main issue is a about the large N (I'm struggling between memory too low and unreachable computation times) so your solution might be enlightening.

Comment: Please see my edited code snippet for a batch version. In theory, this style could use less memory. However, in practice, it appears to still have the same overhead as the standard version. Possibly you could use this for your problem somehow.

Comment: I might be overlooking something, but wouldn't this method require the same amount of memory, after all?
Anyway, it is a good input! Thank you!

Comment: To store dists will require the same amount of memory. However, I am not sure how pdist is implemented internally. It is possible processing chunks of the result will require less temporary memory than doing it all at once. However, I should be clear that I did not verify that. Generally, my advice would be to see if you could work with subblocks of the result if memory is the issue.